# How to detect if a filesystem supports permissions?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, file-permissions, ext4

Recently I ran into an issue when my script extracts temporary files via tar to a folder choosen by the user.

The problem was that if that folder was on a USB stick with `exfat` filesystem, the extracted files loose the permission information that `ext4` and `btrfs` filesystems store with each file.

To solve this I created the following fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FOLDER="/example"
FS=$(stat -f -c %T "$FOLDER")

if [[ "$FS" == "fat"* || "$FS" == "vfat"* || "$FS" == "exfat"* || "$FS" == "ntfs"* || "$FS" == "fuse"* || "$FS" == "msdos"* ]]; then
  echo "Unsupported filesystem!"
  exit
fi
```

While this works, it requires me to keep a list of which filesystems are incompatible with `ext4` permissions, and I'm sure my list is far from complete. Because there exist dozens of exotic filesystems that may have the same issue.

So is there a better way to test if a folder supports permissions without actually having to write a file first? And if not, what filesystems should I add to this list to make it more complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be ok to check if one can change write permission and make it a function:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Checks path support changing write permissions
# @args
#     $1: The path to check (mandatory)
# @return
#     0: Allow changing write permission
#     1: Does not allow changing write permission
#     2: Cannot perform the check
canChangeWritePermission() {
    [ -d "${1:?}" ] || return 2
    __cCWP_tmpFile=$(TMPDIR=$1 mktemp) || return 2

    if
        chmod -w "$__cCWP_tmpFile" && ! [ -w "$__cCWP_tmpFile" ] &&
        chmod +w "$__cCWP_tmpFile" && [ -w "$__cCWP_tmpFile" ]
        then rc=0
        else rc=1
    fi
    rm -f -- "$__cCWP_tmpFile"
    return $rc
}

if canChangeWritePermission "${1:?}" 2>/dev/null
then printf '%s has support for changing write permission.\n' "$1"
elif [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then printf '%s does not allow changing write permission.\n' "$1"
    else printf 'Cannot check %s\n' "$1" >&2
fi
```

Comment: I think your `if` is not necessary. Just doing a `chmod ... && chmod ...; rc=$?` should be sufficient. However, this relies on `chmod` setting this exit code if it can not change the permissions. IMO, it would be more reliable to just take away the write permissions, then write something to the file, and then re-read the file to see if the data has been written or not.

Comment: @user1934428 the explicit `if` condition makes the code logic clearer than storing `rc=$?` as the `rm -f -- "$tmpFile" is mandatory even when the check fails. Testing if the `-w` flag state actually reflects what has been set with `chmod` is good enough (I can't think of a valid scenario where the write flag would have been switched off without actually disallowing write operations).

Answer (score 0):

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
chmod 600 "$tempfile" 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Filesystem supports permissions"
else
    echo "Filesystem does not support permissions"
fi
rm "$tempfile"
```

Comment: This could be improved with some commentary on what your code does.